# Django - Updating multiple models from a form - Data does not saved

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a custom `User` model to manage some profiles user: `is_student`, `is_professor` and `is_executive`

In this model, in addition, I have the `get_student_profile()`,`get_professor_profile()` and  `get_executive_profile()` methods to get the user profiles data of each user from my different views.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_professor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_executive = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_student_profile(self):
        student_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'studentprofile'):
            student_profile = self.studentprofile
        return student_profile

    def get_professor_profile(self):
        professor_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'professorprofile'):
            professor_profile = self.professorprofile
        return professor_profile

    def get_executive_profile(self):
        executive_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'executiveprofile'):
            executive_profile = self.executiveprofile
        return executive_profile
```

In addition each profile user `is_student`, `is_professor` and `is_executive` have their own model in where I manage their own data:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    origin_education_school = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    current_education_school = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    extra_occupation = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class ProfessorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,blank=True)


class ExecutiveProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,      on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,blank=True)
```

Is of this way that in my `User` model I override the `save()` method to denote that the `username` field of an user which is created, to be equal  in their value  to the `slug` belonging to the profile user which will take that user (`StudentProfile`, `ProfessorProfile`, `ExecutiveProfile`):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super(User,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

        # Creating an user with student, professor and executive profiles
        if self.is_student and not StudentProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists() \
            and self.is_professor and not ProfessorProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists() \
            and self.is_executive and not ExecutiveProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
            student_profile = StudentProfile(user=self)
            student_slug = self.username
            student_profile.slug = student_slug

            professor_profile = ProfessorProfile(user=self)
            professor_slug = self.username
            professor_profile.slug = professor_slug

            executive_profile = ExecutiveProfile(user=self)
            executive_slug = self.username
            executive_profile.slug = executive_slug

            student_profile.save()
            professor_profile.save()
            executive_profile.save()
        # And so for all possibles profile combinations
```

To these three profiles which I have three forms in where their own fields are generated

```
class StudentProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentProfile
        fields = ('origin_education_school', 'current_education_school',
        'extra_occupation')

class ProfessorProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfessorProfile
        fields = ('occupation',)

class ExecutiveProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExecutiveProfile
        fields = ('occupation', 'enterprise_name', 'culturals_arthistic','ecological')
```

I access to view profile to user through of this URL:

```
url(r"^profile/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$",
        views.account_profiles__update_view,
            name='profile'
    ),
```

In my function based view `account_profiles__update_view()` I am managing the request of the user, and creating the form instances (`StudentProfileForm`, `ProfessorProfileForm`, `ExecutiveProfileForm`) according to the profile to user (`is_student`, `is_professor` and `is_executive`)

```
@login_required
def account_profiles__update_view(request, slug):
    user = request.user
    # user = get_object_or_404(User, username = slug)

    # empty list
    _forms = []
    if user.is_student:
        profile = user.get_student_profile()
        _forms.append(forms.StudentProfileForm)
    if user.is_professor:
        profile = user.get_professor_profile()
        _forms.append(forms.ProfessorProfileForm)
    if user.is_executive:
        profile = user.get_executive_profile()
        _forms.append(forms.ExecutiveProfileForm)

    # user = get_object_or_404(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, username = slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Create a list with all formularies in which there is some POST
        # operation. This mean if there is one, two or three profiles together
        # or individual
        formularios =[Form(data = request.POST,instance=profile) for Form in _forms]

        if all([form.is_valid() for form in formularios]):
            # Only save dato to database if all formularies that send
            # the user in their request are correct or well formed in their
            # data. Check that all formularies has been filled
            for form in formularios:
                profile = form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user
                profile.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        formularios = [Form() for Form in _forms]

    # Access to class Forms instanced (StudentProfileForm,
    # ProfessorProfileForm, ExecutiveProfileForm), through the __class__
    # pŕoperty which return the class onlying. An this class have another
    # property named __name__ which return the name of string of a class,
    # which is the same name with I did name the form classes
    # (StudentProfileForm, ProfessorProfileForm, ExecutiveProfileForm)
    # Next I call to their string method to grant that I always will return
    # a string and I call to lower.

    # The idea with this is place data into a python dictionarie and access
    # to it
    data = {form.__class__.__name__.__str__().lower(): form for form in formularios}
    data['userprofile'] = profile
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile_form.html', data,)
```

And my `profile_form.html` template I have the following small logic:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if userprofile.user.is_student %}
    <div align="center"><i>My Student Profile data</i></div>
        {% bootstrap_form studentprofileform %}
             {{ studentprofileform.non_field_errors }}
        {% endif %}          
        {% if userprofile.user.is_professor %}
            <div align="center"><i>My Professor Profile data</i></div>
            {% bootstrap_form professorprofileform %}
            {{ professorprofileform.non_field_errors }}
        {% endif %}
        {% if userprofile.user.is_executive %} 
            <div align="center"><i>My Executive Profile data</i></div>  
            {% bootstrap_form executiveprofileform %}
            {{ executiveprofileform.non_field_errors }}
        {% endif %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

I wanted to write all these details to comment the following situation which happen to me:

I render the three forms in my template

Only store data related to the latest user profile selected, this mean:

profiles: `is_student`, `is_professor` and `is_executive`

- User with `is_student` profile ... Save data
- User with `is_professor` profile ... Save data
- User with `is_executive` profile ... Save data
- User with `is_student` and `is_professor` profile: Only save data to `is_professor` profile. Does not save data in `is_student` profile forms fields
- User with `is_student` and `is_executive` profile: Only save data to `is_executive` profile. Does not save data in `is_student` profile forms fields
- User with `is_professor` and `is_executive` profile: Only save data to `is_executive` profile. Does not save data in `is_professor` profile forms fields
- User with `is_student`, `is_professor` and `is_executive` profiles: Only save data to `is_executive` profile. Does not save data in `is_professor` and `is_student` profile forms fields

In this moment, only is taked in account the latest selected profile user and according to it, save their related data and not other.

This is because in my `account_profiles__update_view()` function based view I have this `if` .. sentences logic:

```
if user.is_student:
    profile = user.get_student_profile()
    _forms.append(forms.StudentProfileForm)
if user.is_professor:
    profile = user.get_professor_profile()
    _forms.append(forms.ProfessorProfileForm)
if user.is_executive:
    profile = user.get_executive_profile()
    _forms.append(forms.ExecutiveProfileForm)
```

But, I unknown if I will should consider perform here all the profiles user combinations possibles and create the same combination of form instances possibles too. Is this factible of perform?

I try perfom `account_profiles__update_view()` as a class based view, [here some code about it](https://pastebin.com/pYbxTnCh) but the characterization of profiles and instances forms send to the template, make me that I choose the function based view option.
¿What is the best alternative?

My apologies for the long question, I did want give all details for to better understanding of my code and approach that I want accomplish.
I appreciate highly some support and orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of cleaning some stuff up for you. Let's review each piece.

---

#### models.py

There's no need to probe the model with `hasattr()`. We can rather use the fact that the `OneToOneField` between a User and a Profile will place a reference on both sides of the relation. This means you can simply override your `save()` method as follows:

*Note: You may rather want to create the Profiles using [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/) instead.*

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="User is student")
    is_professor = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="User is professor")
    is_executive = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="User is executive")

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.is_student and getattr(self, 'studentprofile', None) is None:
            StudentProfile.objects.create(
                user=self,
                slug=self.username
            )

        if self.is_professor and getattr(self, 'professorprofile', None) is None:
            ProfessorProfile.objects.create(
                user=self,
                slug=self.username
            )

        if self.is_executive and getattr(self, 'executiveprofile', None) is None:
            ExecutiveProfile.objects.create(
                user=self,
                slug=self.username
            )
```

#### views.py

Again, let's just use the fact that the `OneToOneField` on a user will contain a reference to the Profile:

```
@login_required
def update_view(request):
    user = request.user

    # Populate Forms and Instances (if applicable)
    form_profiles = []
    if user.is_student:
        form_profiles.append({'form': StudentProfileForm, 'instance': user.studentprofile})
    if user.is_professor:
        form_profiles.append({'form': ProfessorProfileForm, 'instance': user.professorprofile})
    if user.is_executive:
        form_profiles.append({'form': ExecutiveProfileForm, 'instance': user.executiveprofile})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = [x['form'](data=request.POST, instance=x['instance']) for x in form_profiles]

        if all([form.is_valid() for form in forms]):
            for form in forms:
                form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        forms = [x['form'](instance=x['instance']) for x in form_profiles]

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile_form.html', {'forms': forms})
```

#### forms.py

Your forms may look something like this:

```
class StudentProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = "Student Form"

    class Meta:
        model = StudentProfile
        fields = (
            'origin_education_school',
            'current_education_school',
            'extra_occupation',
        )
```

#### profile_form.html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for form in forms %}
        <h1>{{ form.title }}</h1>
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I double-checked, and forms are saved correctly.

P.S. If you would like to use a Class-Based View, you can follow the classes defined by this Gist: https://gist.github.com/michelts/1029336

Comment: Hi Daniel, your approach is great. Thanks Now I can save the three/two/one forms instances created. One question: How to can I remove the `StudentProfile`, `ProfessorProfile` and `ExecutiveProfile` when I unselect the `is_student`, `is_professor` and `is_executive` checkbox options? These records does not shown when I unselect checkbox account options profile, but these are saved in the database. I know that is consulting the  specific record and delete it, but I don't know how to manage the uncheck event . My apologies for this new question

Comment: @bgarcial I'm not 100% sure what you mean. It's possible to just add manual fields to a `ModelForm`. For example, you can add `is_student`, `is_professor` and `is_executive` to each form (not linked to the model), and then deal with those fields in the loop.

Comment: I understand. Do you know the reason which `<h1>{{ form.title }}</h1>` in my template does not renderize the title ?

Comment: @bgarcial, yup. You need to add it to the line `[x['form'] for x in ...`

Comment: I type that: `if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = [x['form'](data=request.POST, instance=x['instance'], title=x['title']) for x in form_profiles]` but the titles does not rendered. And when I save the forms, I get that error message `TypeError at /accounts/profile/zidane/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'` Excuse me, is that I am not very familiarized with the list comprehensions

Comment: @bgarcial You can just add the title to the form itself. I've updated my answer ^^